# Prove a star-convex set is simply connected, preserving endpoints

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to prove that a star-connected set $S$ is simply connected, following a rigid definition of simply connected.  Specifically, for any two points $x, y \in S$, and two paths $\gamma_{1}(t), \gamma_{2}(t)$ from $x$ to $y$ with $t \in [a,b]$, there exists a continuous deformation $H(s, t)$, $s \in [0, 1]$ such that:

$H(0, t) = \gamma_{1}(t)$,

$H(1, t) = \gamma_{2}(t)$,

$H(s, a) = \gamma_{1}(a) = \gamma_{2}(a) = x$  for all $s$,

$H(s, b) = \gamma_{1}(b) = \gamma_{2}(b) = y$  for all $s$.

And the image of $H$ lies entirely in $S$.  I'm trying to prove this is true for a domain $S$ such that there exists $z \in S$ such that for all $x \in S$, the line segment $\gamma(s) = (1-s)x + sz$, $s \in [0, 1]$, lies entirely in $S$.  My attempt thus far:

$H(s, t) = \[
\begin{cases}
      (1-2s)\gamma_{1}(t) + 2sz & s\leq 0.5 \\
      (2s-1)\gamma_{2}(t) + (2-2s)z & s\geq 0.5 \\
   \end{cases}
\]
$

Edit:  I was in a hurry typing this and forgot to include: as far as I can tell my formulation fails because it doesn't preserve endpoints for all $s$.  Is there some way to adapt it a little and fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Let $p \in S$ be the center of the star. Define $H_1:[0,1]\times [a,b] \to S$ by $H_1(s,t) = sp+(1-s)\gamma_1(t)$, and note that $H_1(0,t) = \gamma_1(t)$ for all $t$, and $H_1(1,t) =p$ for all $t$. Then define $H_2\colon [0,1]\times [a,b] \to S$ by $H_2(s,t) = (1-s)p+s\gamma_2(t)$ and note that $H_2(0,t) = p$ for all $t$ and $H_2(1,t) = \gamma_2(t)$ for all $t$. Both of them are continuous.

Now define $H\colon [0,1]\times [a,b] \to S$ by $$H(s,t)  =\begin{cases} H_1(2s,t) \mbox{ for }0\leq s \leq 1/2 \\ H_2(2s-1,t) \mbox{ for }1/2 \leq s \leq 1.\end{cases}$$

This seems to match what you have.

Comment: Right sorry I was in a rush when I posted so I forgot to say--my problem is that this doesn't seem to satisfy the endpoints condition.  It seems to me that $H(0.5, 0) = p$, so endpoints are not conserved.  I'm not sure how to make a formulation like this but preserve endpoints at $t=0$ and $t=1$ for all $s$.

Comment: You don't care about $H(1/2,\cdot)$, only about $H(0,\cdot)$ and $H(1,\cdot)$. The point $p$ is just a crutch.

Comment: Right, but the definition I was given specifically states that $H(s, a) = \gamma_{1}(a) = \gamma_{2}(a)$ for all $s$, which this fails for $s=0.5$